# How to make 'echo -e' or 'printf' work in git submodule foreach?

Tags: bash, echo, git-submodules

- `echo -e "\u001b[37;1mtest"` outputs :

> **test**

- `printf "\u001b[37;1mtest"` outputs:

> **test**

- `git submodule foreach -q 'echo "test" '` outputs:

> test 
> test 
> test

- `git submodule foreach -q 'echo -e "\u001b[37;1mtest" '` outputs:

> -e "\u001b[37;1mtest 
> -e "\u001b[37;1mtest 
> -e "\u001b[37;1mtest

- `git submodule foreach -q 'printf "\u001b[37;1mtest\n" '` outputs:

> \u001b[37;1mtest 
> \u001b[37;1mtest 
> \u001b[37;1mtest

How could I print with '\u001b[37;1m' ?

Answer (score 0):

This one is slightly tricky:

- `bash` interprets `\u` escape sequences
- so your two top level commands work when bash itself runs `printf` or `echo`
- `/bin/sh` may or may not be `bash`

The non-bash `printf` and `echo` on your system *don't* handle `\u` escape sequences.  So when `git submodule foreach` runs `sh`, and it's not `bash`, you see what you are seeing.

To get the escape-sequence effect, use the old style `\033` for <kbd>ESC</kbd>.